# Visual Studio 2017 debugging .Net Core 2.0 Using IISExpress, Https, and a non-localhost URL

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, iis-express

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2017 and debugging a web app using SSL. I suspect it's an issue with an untrusted developer certificate but I can't get Visual Studio to trust the cert like it usually does. The issue only happens when trying to launch with an https enabled non-localhost URL.

[image: Debugger error]

The following scenarios work, based on the project settings in the debug section. The project will launch with the App URL, the debugger works, and the SSL URL works.

```
App URL: http://localhost:12345
Enable SSL: https://localhost:43123

App URL: https://localhost:43123
Enable SSL: https://localhost:43123

App URL: http://some-custom-domain:12345
Enable SSL: https://some-custom-domain:43123
```

The following does NOT work and throws the error above when launching the debugger:

```
App URL: https://some-custom-domain:43123
Enable SSL: https://some-custom-domain:43123
```

I have tried deleting my launchsettings.json, removing all localhost certs and repairing my IISExpress install to generate a new cert, deleting the bin/obj folders and rebuilding, deleting the .vs folder and rebuilding.

When I run a Core 1.x project using an HTTPS url it prompts me to trust the cert, and then it runs as normal.

Any insight would be helpful. My workaround is to enforce redirection to HTTPS on my development environment but I'd love to be able to launch right into the HTTPS URL.

Comment: Use Jexus Manager to create a certificate whose CN name matches some-custom-domain, and use it for your site binding instead of the localhost one, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/self-signed.html

Comment: Please state the errors. Text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Please state the URL you are using to connect to the service, and show the certificate used for `https://some-custom-domain`.